# Catch any control key (e.g. \cn and \cx) in perl

Tags: perl

By control key here I mean the control key on the keyboard plus any letter. I can match them individually, by e.g. \cn or \cx, but how can I match all such keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean match in a regular expression? You can use a ranged character class:

```
$contains_ctrl_char = $_ =~ /[\c@-\c_]/;
$contains_ctrl_char = $_ =~ /[\000-\037]/;
$contains_ctrl_char = $_ =~ /[\x{00}-\x{1F}]/;
```

There's probably an appropriate POSIX character class for this, too, though I don't know what it is off hand.

Answer (score 2):

You can match against a character class, i.e.

perl -lne 'print m/[[:cntrl:]]/?"yes":"no"'

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX character class `/[[:cntrl:]]/` is what you want.

It matches character codes 0 .. 0x1F and DEL (0xFF)